# Matrix exponential for $A=\begin{pmatrix}A_{11} & A_{12} \\ 0 & A_{22}\\ \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The entries of the A matrix are all square matrices. Does any one know how to find an expression for the corresponding exponential matrix?

Answer (score 1):

If $$A = \begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ 0 & A_{22}\end{bmatrix},$$

it is known that $$e^A=\begin{bmatrix} e^{A_{11}} & F_{12} \\ 0 & e^{A_{22}}\end{bmatrix},$$

where

$$F_{12} = \int_0^1 e^{(1-u)A_{11}}A_{12}e^{uA_{22}}\, du.$$

Citation: Pade approxiation for the exponential of a block triangular matrix, by Luca Dieci and Alessandra Papini, Linear algebra and its applications , $308 (2000), 183-202.$ Equation $(1.3).$

Comment: Thanks, Siong. However, the attempt over there is to give an approximation. Even I checked ref. [13] of your ref. which is has the same view. Albeit, it is possible to prove this equity by differentiating both sides. I was hoping to find an approach without knowing the expression for F12 beforehand.